# Is it possible to declare a dynamic constant in VB .NET?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, constants

I'm trying to save a timestamp into a constant at the beginning of a program's execution to be used throughout the program. For example:

```
Const TIME_STAMP = Format(Now(), "hhmm")
```

However, this code generates a compiler error - "Constant expression is required." Does that mean all constants in VB .NET have to contain flat, static, hard-coded data? I know that it's possible to initialize a constant with a dynamic value in other languages (such as Java) - what makes it a constant is that after the initial assignment you can no longer change it. Is there an equivalent in VB .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is the readonly keyword.
A time stamp has to be calculated at run time and cannot be constant.

```
ReadOnly TIME_STAMP As String = Format(Now(), "hhmm")
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to make it `Shared Readonly` instead of `Const` - the latter only applies to *compile-time* constants. `Shared Readonly` will still prevent anyone from changing the value.

Java doesn't actually *have* a concept like `Const` - it just spots when `static final` values are actually compile-time constants.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, constants are not dynamic.  If you want a variable to be set once, and not modified again, I believe you are looking for the `ReadOnly` keyword...

```
Public Shared ReadOnly TIME_STAMP = Format(Now(), "hhmm")
```

Note that 'Shared' is optional.

Comment: why are there bracers between `Shared` ?

Comment: Because it is (optional) depending on how the library is designed.

Comment: Chances are, it's not only to me. That probability is *really* low. But why convince you ?